# Mecury editor not working in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am experimenting with mercury editor for the first time in a new app. I have some static pages (no models). I simply configured a static route to these pages that looks like...

get 'online_scheduling_text', to: 'static_pages#online_scheduling_text', as: 'online_scheduling_text'

...and I am able to browse to /editor/online_scheduling_text. I see my text, and I have the took bar, but all of the smaller buttons are greyed out. Also I am not able to put a cursor in the window and edit anything.

Ideas on what I'm missing? This is a rails 3.2.8 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had where the menu bar was grey out is because I did not wrap my static pages in the proper div's like this...

```
<div id="primary" data-mercury="full">
your awesome content here
</div>
```